# How to draw a subview onto UIView using Quartz

Tags: iphone, uiview, quartz-graphics

I'm generating and displaying a tree structure on a UIView in an iPad app. let's call the view ROOTVIEW. All the tree nodes are UIViews too, which has label and UIImage as subviews. When a node is generated from the data source, it will generate a UIView for the node and add to ROOTVIEW as subview. But the problem is, when the tree structure is large, like thousands of nodes, it will use way too much memory.

Because the node's view won't change after added to ROOTVIEW, I come up with a solution: when we get the node's UIView, instead of adding it to ROOTVIEW as subview, we draw it on the ROOTVIEW, and release the node's UIView. so at the end there will be only one view: ROOTVIEW.

I'm not quite familiar with Quartz, how can I draw a subview onto UIView? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is right way. Just render individual views or even parts of your views tree on root image view.
see how to do this here: [Easy or efficient way to copy the bitmap representation from one view to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425002/easy-or-efficient-way-to-copy-the-bitmap-representation-from-one-view-to-another/2425382#2425382)

Comment: Thanks, I think this is what I want. But how can I draw the images iteratively? I can only think of store the images generated from subviews using the above method and store in the root view. when the root view is asked to display, then draw all the images to the root view using drawRect. But it will also using too much memory. How can I draw the subview image to the root view when it's generated and then discard the image altegother?

Comment: renderInContext method renders WHOLE view's tree into single image. So no need to use drawRect.Use single UIImageView as root view then either render whole tree into it and release the tree, or render each view iteratively rather than adding it to tree. Or you can add iteratively images made from nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using `UITableView`? I know that it doesn't directly supported nested nodes, but you will still be better off utilizing `UITableViewController`'s functionality, rather than implementing a full fledged tree component. You can try to customize the cells to look indented to achieve a tree-like visual.

HTH,

Akshay

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the advice of using UITableView, you might also consider using a cache of your own tree-node views. This means that you hold an array of tree-node views, and recycle them - whenever the user scrolls, different data is displayed, but (almost) the same amount of tree nodes is displayed. Just allocate enough tree nodes to fill the visible area, maybe with two-three more for scrolling edges, and every time the user scrolls, update the data in each tree-node. The same technique is used in the UITableview, where it holds cells in the amount that can be displayed (usually 14-20, depending on cell height), The UITalbleView does NOT allocate cells for the amount of rows in the table (which might be hundreds, or thousands!)

Comment: I know that, but in my app, it's required that the user can see the overview of the whole tree and zoom in and out to explore the tree.

Comment: Ouch. Consider just drawing the whole thing directly to the graphics context (overriding DrawRect), or drawing to an offline image and to just scale that image as needed.

Comment: What do you mean by overview of the whole tree? How would you display an overview if your tree has hundreds of nodes? I would suggest you to rethink your UI design.